# Return type object with the same parameters

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to return an array of objects which key names will depend on the parameters the function receives. I have the following:

```
class CountryFilterFormatterService {
  public groupCountriesByRegion(
    groupLabelKey: string,
    groupValuesKey: string,
  ): {[groupLabelKey]: string, [groupValuesKey]: string}[] {
      return [
          {
              [groupLabelKey]: 'foo',
              [groupValuesKey]: 'bar'

        }
    ]
  }
}

export default CountryFilterFormatterService;
```

I would like the function `groupCountriesByRegion` to have the return type of `{[groupLabelKey as string]: string, [groupValuesKey]: Country[]}[]` but I get the following error: `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type`

How can I achieve such return type?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BXAdgFwE4E8BiBLEqAputvOgLZipHoDKxAbrsIdAN4BQ00ADogEYhm0AObokPBCgy5CEAEKYASoRG54yABRduo8Yh4AZMP0IgA0oUwAuaBBnIRAGh3cxEgGpgQiOZZt2Ds46AJS2bADa7gbGphZWALq29ui4jk7QUfo8Xj5+iclBAL4RCeyuuuiEqIjoyJkVurqcTa2tWRKxZv5J0ADkAGbw8H0ubeOZ0TnevhA9tn38YOh9jeNr3EUVCTpbWxyEAB48ZKjQACaEA2CIBHBIaFh4BMSkFFQ09OhMLADcHEA)

Comment: The 'finalGroupedBy' variable has a different type then your return type.

Comment: @Jeroenouw I updated the question to make things a little bit easier to understand. I re-wrote the code to show that it has nothing to do with the return type

Comment: Can you try: [groupLabelKey: string]: string, [groupValuesKey: string]: string}[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in both the type of `groupLabelKey` and the type of `groupValuesKey`, like this:

```
class CountryFilterFormatterService {
    public groupCountriesByRegion<LK extends string, VK extends string>(
        groupLabelKey: LK,
        groupValuesKey: VK,
    ): { [K in LK | VK]: string }[] {
        return [
            {
                [groupLabelKey]: 'foo',
                [groupValuesKey]: 'bar'
            } as { [K in LK | VK]: string }
        ]
    }
}
```

There are two generic type parameters: `LK` and `VK`, corresponding to the (hopefully) [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) of the values passed in for `groupLabelKey` and `groupValuesKey` respectively.  The return type is an array of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), `{[K in LK | VK]: string}`.  This means "an object whose keys are `LK` and `VK`, and whose values at those keys are `string`s".

There's a wrinkle here in that the value `{ [groupLabelKey]: 'foo', [groupValuesKey]: 'bar' }` is not recognized by the compiler as being of the right type.  It sees the generic computed key and widens it all the way to `string`, and therefore the type of that object is inferred to be `{ [k: string]: string }`, and the compiler will complain if you return that as is.  There's an open GitHub issue about this, [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), but for now that's the way it is.

The workaround is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) as I've done above, and add `as { [K in LK | VK]: string }` after the object literal.  There are other workarounds but this one doesn't touch the runtime code.

So, let's see if it works:

```
const x = (new CountryFilterFormatterService()).groupCountriesByRegion("baz", "qux");
// const x: { baz: string; qux: string; }[]

x.forEach(
    v => console.log(v.baz.toUpperCase() + " " + v.qux.toUpperCase())
); // FOO BAR
```

Looks good. I passed in `"baz"` and `"qux"`, and the type of `x` is seen by the compiler to be `Array<{baz: string, qux: string}>`, as you presumably want.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BXAdgFwE4E8BiBLEqAputvOgLZipHoDKxAbrsIdAN4CwAUNL9AA6IARiGbQA5uiT8EKDLkIQAQpgBKhcbnjIAPABkA0tEIAPIsgAmMCPOTiANNABqR0+avQb6XHYB8ACm4+YIkpRH49MCFCEANCTAAuaEN7IJDeSWknMBBERTjE5wNUnj4ASiS2aABtIx9kowAfIoBdJK8fcWgAX2qW9jT09EJURHRkGsH0vk5S6enqzPDI6Nj4tugAcgAzeHhNkvn5xbD+bNz89aTNoTB0Tan57uhIdhq6icNoZpcNjrseo8+C0pt1uGCeNxgNobNATNAALzQfzIQgAdzgSDQWDwBGIpAoVBo9HQTBY-jKZQAdEsZFj5IoVOpNNp-AAiW4ALzZjjZAEdECY2WUANzcAD04ug0OQsJMlWgXPatnEIugAvlnhVat6IK43BMVN26AAomBgAALQJzaAMRG+aUw+AgQhUkDwcT+BhUrlU1DwACq-H4xFgkEIFOgAGpoGzY9HbVSNX7A8HQ+GKWVuKLoJLoNgAPIF6BKACCqm43CAA)

Comment: Sometimes waiting a day or two for the answer makes you understand  deeply the problem

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Since you're providing dynamic keys, you can specify it just once. If you have a fixed set of keys, you can also create an Enum and use that instead on generic `string`

```js
class CountryFilterFormatterService {
  public groupCountriesByRegion(
    groupLabelKey: string,
    groupValuesKey: string,
  ): {[groupLabelKey: string]: string}[] {
      return [
          {
              [groupLabelKey]: 'foo',
              [groupValuesKey]: 'bar'
            
        }
    ]
  }
}

export default CountryFilterFormatterService;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that in the real scenario (I had to edit the question) `groupLabelKey` and `groupValuesKey` have different types. The original type is as follow: `{[groupLabelKey: string]: string, [groupValuesKey]: Country[]}`